# how to set an image to ImageButton background programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imagebutton

I'm coding with Kotlin for Android app. I need to add an image for ImageButton background. I tried ImageButton.setBackgroudResource and ImageButton.setImageResource methods but it would not change.

My code is here:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var imageButton1 = binding.imageButton1
        imageButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage)
}}
```

`imageButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage)` would not set myImage.png to imageButton1.

Comment: You should remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` because you configure view by view binding.

Comment: @ChampChayangkoon I removed `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and it worked! Thank you! Could you tell me why the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` affected the code? Did it rewrite the first setContentView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setImageDrawable and get the drawable from the resources like below

```
imageButton1.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage));
```

or

```
imageButton1.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.myImage));
```